# Finding distance between the center of circumcircle and incircle

Tags: geometry

How to find the distance between circumcircle and inscribed circle in a triangle?
I've found this formula in the internet:
$\sqrt{R^2-2rR}$
Where R is the radius of the circumcircle and r is the radius of the inscribed circle. However I can't prove it.
Here is drawing:
[image]

The red line is indicating the distance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean the formula of Euler? here it is
https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Euler_Triangle_Formula